# Google Colab - unable to upload large data file

Tags: file-upload, google-colaboratory

Using the Upload feature in Google Colab, I was unable to upload a large (~2.4 GB) image segmentation model file (sam_vit_h_4b8939.pth) from my local machine to Google Colab. I could see it listed with a red circle in the Files pane but, after waiting about 10 minutes, I canceled the upload. Also, I issued the Upload command with the Content folder selected, but this and another file were initially listed loose in the top-level folder. I was able to successfully upload a different file (image data in .zip format) and drag it to the Content folder. There was ample space indicated on the Colab virtual hard drive.

Tried to upload a large file to Google Colab and expected it to be successful. Instead, the file was either rejected or the upload timed out, without any error message.

UPDATE 1: I noticed the following error message in cell 1 of the Jupyter notebook I was working on in Google Colab: "Connecting to dl.fbaipublicfiles.com (dl.fbaipublicfiles.com)|13.226.210.111|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2024-01-17 21:18:52 ERROR 403: Forbidden."

Evidently, the model file was not uploaded from the facebookresearch/segment-anything repo; however, I subsequently attempted without success to upload this file from my local machine to Google Colab.

UPDATE 2: I resolved this issue by uploading a smaller segmentation model (sam_vit_b_01ec64.pth).

Answer (score 0):

In the [automatic_mask_generator_example.ipynb](https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything/blob/main/notebooks/automatic_mask_generator_example.ipynb) file on SAM's github, they have the cell if using_colab is true

```py
if using_colab:
    import torch
    import torchvision
    print("PyTorch version:", torch.__version__)
    print("Torchvision version:", torchvision.__version__)
    print("CUDA is available:", torch.cuda.is_available())
    import sys
    !{sys.executable} -m pip install opencv-python matplotlib
    !{sys.executable} -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything.git'

    !mkdir images
    !wget -P images https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything/main/notebooks/images/dog.jpg

    !wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/segment_anything/sam_vit_h_4b8939.pth
```

Whenever I run this cell it successfully gets the vit_h model. Of course, you don't have to install the other content. Alternatively, you could upload the pth file to your drive and then mounting and importing it in a colab cell:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Comment: seateen: Thank you very much for this useful information. tf-newbie